# MongoDB manage access from node js server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a node js server with a MongoDB. Can I do a 2 simultaneous connections to DB with different users?
Here is my connect code:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { DB } = require("../constants");

const connectDB = async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  });
};

export const connect = connectDB;
```

I want make 2 connections, for example:

```
DB1 = mongodb+srv://USER:password@.mongodb.net
DB2 = mongodb+srv://USER1:password@.mongodb.net
```

Is it possible to do this in node js?

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine yes since there are two instances, I think the most obvious response is you will never know until you try :D